# mvn deploy to AWS (ssh via distributionManagement)

Tags: maven, amazon-web-services, maven-3, maven-deploy-plugin

I am working on deploying the WAR file to AWS using Maven. I am planning to use 'mvn deploy' for the same which would ssh the war file to AWS.
I am following http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/examples/deploy-ssh-external.html.

This is my POM file

```
<project>
  ...
  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>ssh-aws</id>
      <url>scpexe://<ec2 instance>.compute-1.amazonaws.com</url>
    </repository>
  </distributionManagement>

  <build>
    <extensions>
      <!-- Enabling the use of FTP -->
      <extension>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
         <artifactId>wagon-ssh-external</artifactId>
         <version>1.0-beta-6</version>
      </extension>
    </extensions>
  </build>
  ..
</project>
```

This is my settings.xml

```
<server>
    <id>ssh-aws</id>
    <username>aws-user</username>
</server>
```

The only issue is that I am unable to figure out the **url in distributionManagement** node of pom.xml.

I am able to ssh in the AWS server by the following.

```
ssh -i ~/pemfile/pemfile-key.pem aws-user@<ec2 instance>.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

But when I run mvn clean deploy, I receive this..

```
Exit code: 1 - Permission denied (publickey). -> [Help 1]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you configured to use the key file in the settings.xml which seemed not to be the case.

Comment: Do you mean the PEM file location? Could you please provide some references or sample code for it? I am unable to understand. Thanks!

Comment: @khmarbaise .. Thanks.. I was totally missing out on the key file in settings.xml.

Comment: @Dexter: Can you please share the files as an answer

Comment: @dexter I know it's pretty old but I'm interested on that too. Can you share how you do such thing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to **add path to your private key**, i.e. pem file along with *server id* and *username* in maven configuration file **settings.xml**, like this:

```
<settings>
...
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>ssh-aws</id>
      <username>aws-user</username>
      <privateKey>/path/to/your/private/key</privateKey>
    </server>
  </servers>
...
</settings>
```